# Supporting lines of closed Jordan curve

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, smooth-manifolds

Given a simple closed Jordan (i.e. continuous) curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2,\ \gamma([a,b])=C_\gamma$, how can I prove that $D_\gamma$ (the set of all interior points of $\gamma$ toghether with the boundary $C_\gamma$) admits exactly two supporting lines in each direction?

A support line for $D_\gamma$ is a line that contain at least one point from $C_\gamma$ but no interior point of $D_\gamma$.

I didn't find any references for that convex geometry question..., but I saw that this property is used in the geometry of constant width curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection of $D_\gamma$ onto any line is  a connected, compact set with nonempty interior: thus, a closed interval of positive length. The endpoints of this interval correspond to supporting lines. The interior points of the interval correspond to lines $L$ such that $D_\gamma\setminus L$ is disconnected: since $D_\gamma$ is a topological disk, the set $D_\gamma\cap L$ must contain some of its interior points.